# Avoid duplicates in SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables and i want to get each purchase expanded by each way of payment:

```
Sales:

id_sale,
sku,
amount,
pieces,

Payments: 

id_way_payment, 
id_sale, 
sku, 
amount
```

A sale can have 1 or more payments.

When I join those tables, if a sale has 3 pieces of the same product, and all 3 were paid with the same i.e.: cash, I get 3 results with the same amount and the same quantity -  becase the Payments table register per each product a row.

If I group by id_way_payment if a sale was by 2 of the same sku will be showed as one instead each one.

I need to get the list of each product and it's ways of payments without discard or duplicate them

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired result set ??

Comment: We need: `DESCRIBE Sales;`, `DESCRIBE Payments;`, your current query, and what Sir Ali said.

Comment: i'll try to get them on monday, i'm not working now.